# Hibernate : from table to class

Tags: java, database, hibernate

As we know, Hibernate allows you to persist a class into a table.

But, can we do the contrary ? Can we directly create a class from an available table ? Can we directly create objects from the lines of an available table ?

Thank you everyone,

Answer (score 0):

You can generate entity classes from database tables at design/development time with the help of Hibernate Tools. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/) is a basic example of it. Before creating any object of an entity, its class must exists.

Comment: Ok, thank you ! It seems to correspond to what I want to do. But, in your example, it seems that the Dbuser.java class is just purely generated from scracth, without already existing, no ? Or, should we just create the class before, like that : public class Dbuser {} and that's all ?

Comment: Hibernate Tools generate java classes from scratch so there is no need to create any empty class.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#toolsetguide):

> several wizards are provided with the Hibernate Eclipse tools. You can use a wizard to quickly generate Hibernate configuration (cfg.xml) files, or to reverse engineer an existing database schema into POJO source files and Hibernate mapping files. The reverse engineering wizard supports customizable templates.

Creating objects from rows in a database table is the primary job of an ORM. So of course that is possible too.

Comment: Ok, I see you're talking about POJO. But, from what I know, you can create Pojo files and all the DAO Pattern only with JDBC (with Statement and ResultSet objects). I mean, you do not even need Hibernate. So, how can we use Hibernate and not JDBC ? Thanks,

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Hibernate runs on top of JDBC. It allows mapping objects to database tables. Whether you want to use it or not is up to you.